# Using GammaRay Client without GUI

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to perform a click on a QT pushButton using GammaRay. I managed to do it using the GammaRay Client GUI. But I need to reproduce it using code or terminal command. Is there any way to do it with GammaRay? Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

For automation and testing I recommend to use Squish, because the purpose of GammaRay is introspection not automation.

https://www.froglogic.com/de/squish/editions/qt-gui-test-automation/

Comment: Squish is very expensive for what I need... Is there any open source alternative?

Comment: Write your own Qt Interface for remote features

Comment: What do you mean? Writing it from scratch? Don’t you think that I could add the feature to GammaRay?

Comment: I don't know how fast you are to analyze the complete GammaRay code, check github, but I guess is easier to add your own IPC Interface (TCP) and add your required methods, because you want to execute only button clicks, but be aware only fire and forget is not a good test. Normal way is to stimulate and then check your GUI.